# Want to make a regular expression that matches the following string

Tags: python, regex, expression

I have to make a regexp that matches this:

ORIGIN atcgt **--(a dna sequence varying in length)--** //

But my skills aren't that good

Comment: Please explain the pattern clearly.

Comment: How would you go about even starting with a regexp in Python?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this pattern `^[ATCGU]+$`

```
import re
dnpattern = re.compile("^[ATCGU]+$")
print dnpattern.match("ATC").group()
```

Comment: With `U`?  I'm surprised, aren't there only four base pairs in the DNA?

Comment: @Alfe I know nothing about DNA and RNA but wiki says (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA_sequencing) `commonly represented as A, C, G, T, and U`

Comment: Ah, okay.  Have to ask one of my fellows concerned with microbiology about that one ;-)